# Slice up an image into tiles

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

Given a loaded `Bitmap` object.  I want to slice up this image into 256x256 tiles and save out each tile as a jpg file.

You may think this as a Silverlight Deep Zoom sort task and you'd be right.

I've got a solution using WPF but I would prefer a solution that would work in the .NET 2.0 framework.  GDI+ is not somewhere I've spent any amount of time.

Anyone know how I could go about this?  I can't seem to find a "Create Bitmap from a specified rectangle sort of method".  I'd be surprised if one doesn't exist but perhaps I can't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle, PixelFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) to crop out a 256x256 region of a source image.  This works in .NET 2.0.

Comment: Thanks Reed, that seems pretty straightforward, its obvious that if you want to cut a slice of something you'd call its Clone method. :P

Comment: Yeah - Horrible name for that method, but it works quite well.