# What is the fastest way to slice an image into tiles?

Tags: image, optimization, tiles, geotools

I need to slice an image (size: 14043 × 9933) into 256 x 256 set of tiles with different zoom levels (number of tiles) in the most efficient way. I've been using gdal2tiles.py(it comes with GDAL), but I wonder if there's other options out there, maybe Geotools have this functionality? or any other alternatives (I don't need and and geo-referencing to the tiles).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`gdal2tiles` is a nice thing and can do many projections, but it's slow for simple raster tile pyramids and needs a lot of memory. [`dzsave`](http://libvips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/making-deepzoom-zoomify-and-google-maps.html) is faster and more efficient with RAM. On this laptop with a 25k x 25k RGB JPG file I see:

```
$ time gdal2tiles.py -p raster ../wac_nearside.jpg x
Generating Base Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Generating Overview Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
real    3m51.728s
user    3m48.548s
sys 0m2.992s
peak memory 400mb
```

But with `dzsave` I see:

```
$ time vips dzsave ../wac_nearside.jpg y --suffix .png
real    0m36.097s
user    1m39.900s
sys 0m6.960s
peak memory 100mb
```

It would be faster still, but almost all the time is being spent in PNG write. If I drop back to the default JPEG tiles I see:

```
$ time vips dzsave ../wac_nearside.jpg y
real    0m10.791s
user    0m20.268s
sys 0m4.672s
peak memory 100mb
```

More than 20x faster than `gdal2tiles`.

`dzsave` can also do the centring for you automatically, so there's no need for the extra `gdal_translate` step.

Answer (score 0):

try this thread:

[Slice up an image into tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434140/slice-up-an-image-into-tiles)