# Streaming Large Image with pan & Zoom & Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, openlayers

I have large 500MB size image I want to show this image like map with zoom and pan features in ASP.net. I found OpenLayers for this but anyone can share any working example using any framework/library to achieve this functionality in ASP.net

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to make some smaller images(Mipmapping http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap ) or/and cut them in smaller parts. ([Slice up an image into tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434140/slice-up-an-image-into-tiles))

Think about, you can't see all the pixels of 500mb data. Only transfer what you actually see.

Comment: if we go for slicing then what about zoom in and out levels what if user want to see complete image

Comment: Combine the methods. Make a piramid of it. 1 image reduced to 1024x768 (top level), then slice it to 4 images of 1024x768 (second level), etc.. The zoom level determines the level your on. (this is how google maps works) You only need to think on what images you should send to the gui/client. Here's some example: graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2005_fall/www/Lectures/… See image pyramid.

Comment: As @JeroenvanLangen suggests, you need  some kind of "Map Tile System". For a good overview, have a look at the [Bing Maps Tile System] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i found one answer which i like to share with you. here is the code

```
private static void Split(string fileName, int width, int height)
{
    using (Bitmap source = new Bitmap(fileName))
    {
        bool perfectWidth = source.Width % width == 0;
        bool perfectHeight = source.Height % height == 0;

        int lastWidth = width;
        if (!perfectWidth)
        {
            lastWidth = source.Width - ((source.Width / width) * width);
        }

        int lastHeight = height;
        if (!perfectHeight)
        {
            lastHeight = source.Height - ((source.Height / height) * height);
        }

        int widthPartsCount = source.Width / width + (perfectWidth ? 0 : 1);
        int heightPartsCount = source.Height / height + (perfectHeight ? 0 : 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < widthPartsCount; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < heightPartsCount; j++)
            {
                int tileWidth = i == widthPartsCount - 1 ? lastWidth : width;
                int tileHeight = j == heightPartsCount - 1 ? lastHeight : height;
                using (Bitmap tile = new Bitmap(tileWidth, tileHeight))
                {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tile))
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, tile.Width, tile.Height), new Rectangle(i * width, j * height, tile.Width, tile.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    }

                    tile.Save(string.Format("{0}-{1}.png", i + 1, j + 1), ImageFormat.Png);
                }
            }
    }
}
```